# Unable to set initial region in mapview to current location when permision is asked

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-maps

I am trying to get the map to show the current location when the screen starts.
The code operates well when location permission has been already granted.
When permissions are asked, the map takes the default value from the state before updating the state.
I am using redux in my application.

LocationScreen.js

```
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            this.props.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_LOCATION', location:{latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude}})
        });
    }


    render() {    
        const location = this.props.location;
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="#ffffff" barStyle="dark-content" />
                <View pointerEvents="none" style={{zIndex:99 ,position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                    <Image pointerEvents="none" style={{height:59,width:40, marginBottom:60}} source={require('../../../assets/marker1.png')}/>
                </View>
                <MapView
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
                    style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: location.latitude,
                        longitude: location.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.00005,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0021,
                    }}
                    onRegionChange={(region) => {
                        this.props.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_LOCATION', location:{latitude:region.latitude,longitude:region.longitude} });
                    }}
                >
                    {/* <Marker
                        coordinate={{latitude:location.latitude,longitude:location.longitude}} 
                    /> */}
                </MapView>
                <View style={styles.bottomView}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 40, width:'80%', backgroundColor:'#00665c', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginHorizontal:'10%', marginBottom:20 }}
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details_one_reg')}
                    >
                        <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Next</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{color:'gray',marginLeft:30,marginBottom:25}}>Drag and drop pin on the location of the Shop</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:16, marginLeft:30, marginBottom:4}}>Location</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
      location : state.location, 
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LocationScreen);
```

statetree

```
export const stateTree = {
    auth:{
        mobile_no:7397440807,
        otp:100000,
    },
    location:{
        latitude:0,
        longitude:0,
    },
    inventory : [
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work I had to use the onRegionChangeComplete handler of MapView in conjunction with the region property.  The constructor of the component asks for Location Permissions then gets the current position and sets the state.  The MapView has a property tied to the state set in the constructor.  You can probably streamline this.

It's important to note the onChangeRegion is an event that fires continuously while the map is moving and therefore is not called when the component first loads.  The onChangeRegionComplete is fired when the map settles and fires when the component loads.

```
interface ExampleProps {

}

interface ExampleState {
    region: any
}

export class ExampleComponent extends Component<ExampleProps, ExampleState> {

    constructor(props: ExampleProps) {
        super(props);

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
            this.requestLocationPermission();
        }

        this.state = {
            region: {
                longitude: 0,
                latitude: 0,
                longitudeDelta: 0.004,
                latitudeDelta: 0.009
            }
        };

        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                console.log(position);
                this.setState({
                    region: {
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.004,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.009
                    }
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                // See error code charts below.
                console.log(error.code, error.message);
                throw error;
            },
            { 
                showLocationDialog: true,
                forceRequestLocation: true, 
                enableHighAccuracy: true, 
                timeout: 15000, 
                maximumAge: 10000 
            }
        );

    }

    async requestLocationPermission() {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
              title: "Example App",
              message: "Example App access to your location "
            }
          );
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("You can use the location");
            alert("You can use the location");
          } else {
            console.log("location permission denied");
            alert("Location permission denied");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err);
        }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                provider = { PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
                style = {styles.map}
                region = {this.state.region} 
                onRegionChange={ region => {
                    //console.log("Region Changed");
                    //this.setState({region});
                 } }
                onRegionChangeComplete={ region => {
                    console.log("Region change complete");
                    this.setState({region});
                 } }
                showsUserLocation={ true } >
            </MapView>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
          flex: 1
      },
      map: {
          flex: 1
      }
  })
```